# Date from and to filter without time c# mvc

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 inputs in an mvc application:
date_from and date_to (this are Date only on view, not DateTime)

when I call a service to get the result filtered by those values I call

```
Result result = client.GetResults(from = date_from, to = date_to);
```

the logic in the GetResults do a linq on a EF5 like this:

```
context.Results.Where(r=> r.date >= date_from && r.date <= date_to);
```

since the view only have the date part of the DateTime, if I pass 
from : 2013-12-01 
to : 2013-12-01

The only results i get are those on hour 0:0:0

What I want to do is call the service with the to as the end of the date.

- NOTE: I don't want to change service logic because time is used in other places.
- NOTE2: I don't want to send date_to.AddDays(1) since it will show me data from another date at 0:0:0 hour.

What's a good solution ? I came up with date_to.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1) but don't think is a good way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that's not a good solution?

Comment: why do you think it isn't a good solution? i guess it is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Looks like getting the end of the day this way is kinda hacky, maybe I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to add a day but change the upper bound to be exclusive:

```
var lowerBoundInclusive = date_from;
var upperBoundExclusive = date_to.AddDays(1);
context.Results.Where(r=> r.date >= lowerBoundInclusive && 
                          r.date < upperBoundExclusive);
```

Half-open intervals like this are nice, as they naturally abut - you can use the exclusive upper bound of one interval as the inclusive lower bound of the next one, etc - and every value will fall into exactly one interval. It also means that each boundary is nice round value, which is easy to read.

EDIT: Okay, with the comments it sounds like we're getting somewhere - the problem is that .NET uses `DateTime` when you're dealing with both "just dates" and "dates and times". Typically when expressing an interval with dates, you use an *inclusive* interval ("I'm on holiday Monday to Friday") whereas with dates and times you use an *exclusive* upper bound ("My first meeting is 3:00-4:00, my second is 4:00-5:00." - at 4:00 your first meeting has finished and the second one has started.)

I would recommend writing two methods, one of which can call the other:

```
// This is *inclusive* of both bounds
public XYZ GetResultsByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    return GetResultsByDateAndTime(fromDate.Date, toDate.Date.AddDays(1));
}

// This is *exclusive* of the upper bound
public XYZ GetResultsByDateAndTime(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var results = context.Results.Where(r=> r.date >= from && r.date < to);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is better than the add/remove - especially if some funky day, they decide to make DateTime resolution higher : )

Comment: like i said on my note, the service use the time part logic. doing this will break a request with DateTime using the time part. Also any input with a time different than 0:0:0 may return wrong results.

Comment: @Bart: To be honest, your question is far from clear. You've said that `date_from` and `date_to` are date-only, so presumably they already have a time of 00:00:00. I would *expect* this to work fine with EF, and that's the only part my code affects. I wasn't suggesting changing any of the other logic.

Comment: @JonSkeet are date-only on the view. But this is not the only view I call the GetResults method, where sometimes time matter and other don't. Sorry if it's not clear (english not my native), I tryied to be clear with the notes and all explanation, don't know how to make it more clear than it is.

Comment: @Bart: Are you saying you want the same method to do different things based on whether you just pass in dates or whether you pass in dates with times? Don't do it! Break it out into two different methods. (Or put the "add a day" part in the caller when dealing with dates.)

Comment: @JonSkeet with the edit, we have an amazing answer, specially for pointing out the example of the meeting of 4:00 one finished. so true. Thanks! loved it.

Comment: @Bart: Phew - glad we got to the bottom of it:)